# ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I am currently trying to do this merge to insert / update table in this other table in another database via a database link. I am however receiving this error:

```
**ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation**
```

I have tried altering the session to set the global_names to TRUE. However; once I do that, I receive the following error after compiling my stored procedure:

**Error:ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-02085: database link  TEST connects to TEST**

What other options do I have to try and get this to work?

Below is my code to merge:

```
MERGE INTO table@TEST T
USING (SELECT FROM,
            TO_,
       trunc(utc_hr) as DATA_DATE_DT,  
            UTC_HR,
            DATA_TYPE,
            VALUE_NB,
            LOCAL_TIME_TS
    FROM    VIEW_A
  ) S ON (
                T.FROM = S.FROM_TX
        AND T.TO = S.TO_TX
            AND T.TIMESTAMP_ = S.UTC_HR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
        SET T.VAL                = S.value_nb,
            T.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = S.LOCAL_TIME_ts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT 
        (
          FROM,
          TO,
          DATE_,
          TIMESTAMP_,
          VAL,
          LOCAL_TIMESTAMP )
        VALUES   
         (S.FROM_TX,
          S.TO_TX,
          S.data_date_dt,
          S.utc_hr,
          S.value_nb,
          S.LOCAL_TIME_ts);
```

Comment: Create a materialized view of table@TEST on local schema and then try doing a merge

Comment: it seems to work when i created a duplicate table of it in my local schema, but i can't seem to make the merge when trying to go across the dB link.

Comment: This query looks suspicious. `select FROM, ...` (you use in `using`) is invalid. Other comments (written under Dmitry's answer) suggest that there are doubts about actual database link name. I'd rather see code which actually compiles and doesn't raise unnecessary comments regarding its correctness, but let people focus on real problem. But, if you post an invalid code, how can anybody be sure whether what you posted really looks like this or not?

Comment: from is the name of the column haha

Comment: ive tried recreating that samea table =locally and it works, but when i try to do it across the dB link i receive a 'global_names' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams088.htm#REFRN10065):

"GLOBAL_NAMES specifies whether a database link is required to have the same name as the database to which it connects."

So you need to make a database link with correct name of the linked database (including domain if it is present). Correct database link name should be TEST1 in your example. You can't rename existing link, so you'll have to create a new database link from scratch.

Comment: The dB link's name is the same as the dB name... (I think I read of this before as well). so i am not sure what is going on.

Comment: In your example, database link name is TEST, not TEST1.

Comment: that must have been a typo (sorry!), the dB link is TEST but i am still encountering the same issue :(

Comment: I'm not sure it's a typo. For example... You're making a database link by typing: CREATE DATABASE LINK TEST CONNECT TO TEST... Right? Because you have TNSNAMES file with a db connection named TEST. But.. at init file of your remote linked database it has other global_name! It named TEST1.  So you need to make a database link that will be named the same as SID global_name in init file of linked db, not as your db connection in TNSNAMES.